# I don't understand the use of past perfect in this sentence

Tags: past-tense

> Philadelphia’s Kilynn Lunsford **had been conceiving** her first solo album since she was a young teen. Growing up through the MTV era of Missy Elliot, Timbaland and the Swing Mob collective, and drawn towards its “sometimes ridiculous, but overloaded” qualities, she found herself returning to that state of emerging adulthood when the moment for a solo record finally arose.

Does it mean she began conceiving it before she was a young teen and finished it after or during she was a young teen .The past perfect seems strange here with since . The past perfect implies that her solo album had been  completed and that it took some time  (continuous).

In fact I understand the use of past perfect here but what seems weird is the association with since . Past perfect is justified because she had been "thinking" of it before the moment of doing it finally arose

https://evernever-records.bandcamp.com/album/custodians-of-human-succession

Comment: I think it's an unusual / clumsy use of ***conceive*** - whether it leads to *perception / understanding* or *pregnancy*, conception is usually a fairly rapid process! Perhaps an alternative such a *developing, nurturing,...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think she meant to say, "conceiving *of*", as in, coming up with the concept for an album, which is definitely not the same thing as "conceiving" an album. Ew

Comment: @gotube: That was my understanding anyway. But in *my* universe, you usually *conceive / come up with a concept / idea* in minutes / hours / days. After which you might spend months / years / decades ***developing*** that concept - but you wouldn't normally spend that long conceiving it in the first pace.